# Building a simple site using ASP.Net MVC 3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using mvc3 to build a simple site with 5 static pages. I'm just wondering what the best practice is in this situation. So far I have only one 'Page' Controller which has 5 functions, each returning the appropriate view.

I've also updated the global.asax file to use:

```
routes.MapRouteLowercase(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Page", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

I realise that the general rule is use one controller for each logical unit so I figure this works out okay for a small site?

Is this a suitable approach or should I do it differently?

Thanks.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend MVC, If you are going for static pages, simply use .html files as Jakub mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is fine.

However, if you have just *static* pages, why do you use MVC at all? You can just deploy a bunch of .html files and be done with it.

Comment: Also, you can use routing as well even without asp.net mvc.  `routes.MapPageRoute` will allow you to create a url which doesn't exactly match the path on disk (although going to the path on disk will work as well).

Comment: Thanks Jakub. I was going to build the site just as static html pages but I wanted to have the option to provide friendly urls without having to tamper with IIS :-)

Comment: Sorry Andy, how do I use routes.MapPageRoute with static pages?